# Preprocessor Macro for watchOS version number

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos

`WKInterfaceTextField` is only available in `watchOS 6.0`, so I am needing to exclude the @property from `watchOS` versions lower than 6.0.

Is there a preprocessor macro that I can use in the `.h` file to exclude the `@property` unless it is `watchOS 6.0`?

Comment: I *think* you can do ```@available( watchOS 6, * )``` just like with iOS, but if that fails, how about ```#if __WATCH_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __WATCHOS_6_0```

Comment: `#if __WATCH_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __WATCHOS_6_0` was what I needed. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
#if __WATCH_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __WATCHOS_6_0
```

in your header file to conditionally compile the property.

Then, for completeness - the often used *iOS* check (albeit used in code, in your `.m` file) e.g.

```
if ( @available( iOS 13, * ) )
```

becomes e.g.

```
if ( @available( watchOS 6, * ) )
```

for the watch. For multiplatform this becomes e.g.

```
if ( @available( iOS 13, watchOS 6, * ) )
```